# How to solve error in ionic 2 application using angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Hi all How to Fix the `bug` in ionic 2 application using angular2,Actually I'M developing ionic 2 application, we trying to filter the `list of items in list page` so we have used `type script codes`, we got some error in `visual studio code`and list of items also not filtering in mobile application, we don't know where we have did the mistake, so please check below given image and help us to solve this error. thanks..

**My type script code:-**

```
  let searchTerm: string = '';
    this.activitys = data.items.sort((a, b) => {
       return this.activitys.filter((activity) => {
        return activity.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
    });
```

- the error is occurred in this line `this.activitys = data.items.sort((a, b) => {`

[image]

**My html code:-**

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionInput)="loadActivitysWithAuth()"></ion-searchbar>
```

**Need to filter below given field:-**

```
<h2 (click)="gotoResourceListPage(activity)">{{activity.name}}</h2>
```

- we knew we did some `syntax` error in type script so please check and update the solution thanks...

Comment: are you trying to sort after filter? or trying to set a sorting comparison function? not really able to get the intention

Comment: Could you hover over that highlighted text.. and let us know what error it is saying?

Comment: @pankaj parker thanks for valuable comment, the error showing like :- [ts] Argument of type '(a: Activity, b: Activity) => Activity[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: Activity, b: Activity) => number'.
       Type 'Activity[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: @suraj we just trying to filter the list of events ?...we almost got the answer if you fix the bug it's really useful to us.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the below function in an another function and call the same in your HTML file

```
filterItems(searchTerm): void {
            this.activitys = [];
            this.userPoolsAuthClient.getClient().activitysList().subscribe(
              (data) => {
                this.activitys = data.items.filter((activity) => {
                  return activity.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                });
              });

     }
```

Call the below function in your HTML

```
setFilteredItems() {

  return this.filterItems(this.searchTerm);

}
```

and your HTML goes like this

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionInput)="setFilteredItems()"></ion-searchbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to sort filtered list:

```
let searchTerm: string = '';
    this.activitys = data.items.filter((activity) => {
        return activity.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    }).sort(/*sort comparison function*/);
```

[Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) takes a comparison function which is basically a swap condition.

Comment: Hi suraj thanks for your answer, we have used your code ,then main thing i have forget to remove this line ;-  `this.activitys = data.items;` of code in image, then this is my html code :-  `<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionInput)="loadActivitysWithAuth()"></ion-searchbar>`  whenever we typed events name in search box  it's `loading` does not filtering the items, can please check this and update.....thanks..

Comment: HI Suraj I have updated the code image in question and added html code also....please help us...thanks suraj..

Comment: if activitys is not `data.items` you have to filter `data.items`

Comment: hi suraj have you checked my html codes?...because it's not filtering again... can you please check it again suraj.... then i have updated like this:-  `this.activitys = data.items.filter((activity) => {` is this perfect?

Comment: your `this.activitys` is local to your function` depends on where you want to show the filtered items and also what sorting condition you need to use.

Comment: filter is my main importance than sorting of data, based on search input i need to filter `data.items`